# Insert variable into another new variable

Tags: php, mysql

how can I insert a variable into a new variable that i am creating?
I would to insert into $txt the $array[0] created before.
How do I do?

regards

````
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","user","pass","db");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sets   = "SELECT grp_phone FROM groups WHERE grp_onoff='YES'ORDER BY id ASC";

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$sets)){
    $array = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        $array[] = $r[0];
        
   }

$group = fopen("/tmp/group_70000.txt", "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = 'SET Station_Group   "1": "1": "70000"
    {
    Attached_Stations = {".$array[0]"}
    }';
    fwrite($group, $txt);
    fclose($group);
$conn->close();```
````

Comment: it's a normal assignment, $txt = $array[0]

Comment: not really. If you look at $txt variable, is a "text". If i do like exposed in question result is "SET Station_Group   "1": "1": "70000"
    {
    Attached_Stations = {".$array[0]"}
    }" .
As you can see it just print {".$array[0]"} and NOT, for instance, {"100"}

Comment: `{'.$array[0].'}` or `{" '.$array[0].' "}`

Comment: i need to preserve the double "" as part of the text. Last result should be, for example, {"100"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `{" '.$array[0] .' "}` you get your desired value.
Take a look

```
<?php

$array[0] = "100";//example

 $txt = 'SET Station_Group   "1": "1": "70000"
    {
    Attached_Stations = {" '.$array[0] .' "}
    }';
    
echo $txt;
```

You get

```
SET Station_Group   "1": "1": "70000"
    {
    Attached_Stations = {" 100 "}
    }
```